# Equation numbering in Pages 6.2

Tags: macos-sierra, iwork

I am trying to number my equations in Pages 6.2 on macOS. I have Mathtype but that has a lot of bugs so i use the equation editor in Pages. I have tried also LaTeXiT it doesn't do a good job either.

My question is how to number equations in Pages on the right side? Your help will be appreciated.

Until now i have managed to do this...
[image: Figure 1]